# Is torque important when drilling hole in ceramic tile?

Tags: tile, drill, hole

I want to drill a 2-3cm diameter hole in a ceramic tile. There are diamond-coated hole saw bits, and I read that a cordless drill is recommended if water is used for cooling. I own a 10.8V 30Nm torque drill, but there are more powerful 45 and 85Nm versions too. Is my drill OK for this, or should I invest in a more powerful one?

Comment: Torque should be maxed, the drill should not be yielding to the material. It's ceramic so you don't need to worry about it work hardening.  Other than that, drilling through any material is about feeds and speeds - feed being insertion rate and speed being drill RPM. When you get it right, *you know it*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a professional, but have drilled a lot of holes in masonry.  For a tile, I don't think that the torque will matter much, just chuck it, set it to high speed and drill.  Drill a test hole in a piece of scrap first, so you will know what to expect.  I think your toughest problem will be trying to get the hole started on your center accurately. Nicking the tile with a punch may help.

Drilling an 8" x 3/4 inch hole into 10 year old concrete will require a bit more torque.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to push hard in fact high torque can crack tile, I use high speed and water as a lubricant with ceramic and clay once you punch through the glaze back off on the pressure, porcilin I maintain a constant force until almost completely through.